# filtering out empty dictionary keys to calculate max

Tags: python

I am having trouble filtering out empty values when creating a dictionary.

```
ConsoMax = dict([(key, max([int(i) for i in values])) for key, values in consodict.items()])
```

My issue is that I have some keys in consodicts that have no items, and thus get an error. How can I find the max for only consodict.items() that exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `if values` in your comprehension to check for empty values.

```
dict([(key, max([int(i) for i in values])) for key, values in consodict.items() if values])
```